# Determine extrema of a multivariate function defined on a set

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, multivalued-functions

Given a function $$f(x,y)=2+2x^2+y^2$$ and the set $$A:=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2 | x^2+4y^2\leq 1\}$$ and $f:A\to\mathbb R$ how do I determine the global and local extrema on this set? Normally I would not find this hard since it would just be determining $\nabla f=0$ however I am not sure how this works when $A$ is not something simple like $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: $A$ is not even closed, so existence of global extrema is not guaranteed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that we are restricted to the set $A$ doesn't change the principle at hand. The Extreme Value Theorem states that if the domain is closed and bounded then there exists a maximum (minimum). Your domain is not closed, so we cannot use this theorem, but if we look at the closed ellipse (call it $\bar{A}$) then we can guarantee a max (min).

We then use the technique we know: check where $\nabla f=0$, and all maxima (minima) occur at either these points or on the boundary. In this case we have

$$\nabla f=(4x,2y)=0\implies x=y=0$$

This gives one critical point. We can analytically check, but based on the fact that this function is always increasing from the origin this must be a minimum. As such, $f$ has a minimum at $(0,0)$.

What about a maximum? This function doesn't have a maximum, because as we approach the border of the ellipse this function keeps getting larger, but never achieves a maximum. If we included the boundary of the ellipse, then we would have a maximum on the boundary, and there are several ways of approaching this problem, such as Lagrange Multipliers or paramaterization. Since this was not in the scope of the question, I'll leave it at that.

**Edit** If we are to consider the boundary as part of the domain, then the problem can be solved a few ways. I'll detail two of them.

The single variable calculus way of doing it is through parameterizations. We can actually parameterize the boundary of the domain with the following equations

$$x=\cos(t),\;\;y=\frac{1}{2}\sin(t),\;\;0\leq t<2\pi$$

As a single variable problem this then reads

$$g(t)=f(x,y)=2+2x^2+y^2=2+2\cos^2(t)+\frac{1}{4}\sin^2(t)$$

The derivative is

$$0=g'(t)=-4\cos(t)\sin(t)+\frac{1}{2}\sin(t)\cos(t)\implies\sin(t)=0\mbox{  or }\cos(t)=0$$

As such the boundary has critical points whenever $t=0,\pi/2,\pi,3\pi/2$. Plugging in these values for $t$ into $g$ gives a maximum value of $4$, occuring both at $(1,0)$ and $(-1,0)$.

The multivariate approach is to use Lagrange Multipliers. We seek to minimize $f$ subject to the constraint $g(x,y)=x^2+4y^2=1$. This gives the auxiliary equation

$$L(x,y,\lambda)=2+2x^2+y^2-\lambda(x^2+4y^2-1)$$

The derivatives are

$$L_x=4x-2\lambda x=0\implies x=0\mbox{  or }\lambda=2$$
$$L_y=2y-8\lambda y=0\implies y=0\mbox{. or }\lambda=\frac{1}{4}$$
$$L_\lambda=x^2+4y^2-1=0$$

Since $\lambda$ cannot be both $2$ and $1/4$, we have either $x=0$ or $y=0$, which gives points of $(\pm1,0)$ and $(0,\pm1/2)$. This gives us the same maximum.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. However, I realise that now that you say this I mistyped the problem, it *is* meant to be $\leq$ and not $<$. So how does this change the problem at hand? The minimum at (0,0) is still preserved. Could I ask you to elaborate on how this would change the finding of the maximum?

Comment: How does this approach with lagrange multipliers work if the function isn't in terms of x^2?
As in, if I have $M=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 : 3x^2+y^2\leq6\}$ and $f(x,y)=xy+1$. Then if I find the Hessian/Jacobian for $M^\circ$ I find that $(0,0)$ is a saddle point, and if I consider $\partial M$ then I see that, using your approach, $L(x,y,\lambda) = xy+1 - \lambda (3x^2+y^2-6) \implies \: L_x = y-6\lambda x, \: L_y = x-2y\lambda, \: L_\lambda = -y^2-3x^2+6$. And so I find $\lambda = \pm \frac 1 {\sqrt{12}}$. What can I conclude about this now? Or is this method not a good idea for this?

Comment: Since you know $\lambda$, you can replace it into your first two equations, set them equal to $0$, then solve for $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Thanks - but then what does this tell me about which is a maximum and which is a minimum? Or, rather, how do I conclude it?

Comment: Well, from here you should get exactly two solutions, one for each $\lambda$. One of them has to be the maximum and the other has to be the minimum, right? Plug them into $f$ and see which is bigger.

Comment: I'm...sorry for being this slow. But you don't get individual points, no? It just ends up as $L_x = y-\frac{6}{\sqrt{x}}=0$, $L_y = x-\frac{2}{\sqrt{12}} y$ and setting these equal to zero just gives a band of solutions. Or is that to say there's an infinite amount of global maxima and minima?

Comment: To be blunt, at this point the question is moving in a different direction. At the outset this was a question for a *specific* question that has been answered. If you'd like another question answered to the fullest, you should either post that question separately or ask a more general question. Make sure it is clear that you are either asking about "how to solve this general problem" or "how to solve this system of equations."

Answer (score 1):

Since the domain is compact, the function must attain both maximum and minimum values. If you work in the interior of the set, your approach is right and you get a minimum at zero and no maximum value.

Then, over the border, you get that $x^2=1-4y^2$, so $f$ becomes $f(y)=2+2(1-4y^2)+y^2$ which is a real valued function that you only need to optimize over $ y \in [-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}]$ and you will be done.

Comment: Thank you. I've been told this function has two bounds on the ellipse. Why? Simply optimising this gives me $f'(y)=-14y$ which only has one root, whcih is then the maximum. But what about this other extrema?

Comment: That's the solution for $y$, try finding the actual solution to the problem. ;)